# Como guardar un grafico d3js como un archivo de imagen en el servidor

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, d3.js

Tengo un mapa de calor creado con d3js y necesito guardar este grafico como una imagen en el servidor y que esta pueda ser consultada para luego cargarla en la aplicación o incluirla en un PDF, pero no se cual es la mejor manera o la mas adecuada para hacerlo.

El front de la aplicación esta realizado con Angular y los microservicios están creados con Spring-boot

Aclaro que soy nuevo en el foro así que no tengo claro como realizar correctamente las preguntas, cualquier sugerencia es bien recibida.